# Django runserver giving a 301 error

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-1.7

I'm trying to setup a development version of a Django site (developed by someone else) so that I can make edits and test before putting changes live.  I'm getting a `HTTP 301` error when I try going into `127.0.0.1:8000`.

I've tried other ports to ensure I'm not already using it.

I believe the settings should allow me to run this app, for example I've got:

```
DEBUG = True 
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

The live site is running from `HTTPS` so I figure there is something within `settings.py` which is specifying SSL but I cannot find anything.

Two questions:

1. Is there any way to emulate HTTPS using runserver?
2. If not, what should I be looking for which might be forcing HTTPS?

Comment: The [`SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#secure-ssl-redirect) setting was added in Django 1.8. There could be a custom middleware in your [`MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#middleware-classes) setting.

Comment: HTTP 301 is not an error code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never managed to get this running using runserver.  In the end I set it up on a apache server and it ran fine